# How to grab the individual address from a mail group on Outlook?

Tags: python, outlook

I try to list all the recipients I send emails to by using MAPI.

On MSDN, I found a script which can complete this task. One question is, the mail group only shows the group address. But I want to list all the individual addresses within the group.

Anyone know if this is possible?

```
recips = message.Recipients
for recip in recips:
    pa = recip.PropertyAccessor
    smtpAddress = pa.GetProperty(PR_SMTP_ADDRESS)
```

Answer (score 0):

Process the Recipient.AddressEntry.Members collection recursively. It will be null for the recipients who are not distribution lists.

Comment: It works. Many thanks. But the result is the display name. Is it possible to show the smtp address?